# How to check for the font pattern or style of a copied font?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to distinguish the font family or style of some particular style like , `ℍ` or such which can be created using onlin font generators.

My current `font-style` in CSS is:

```
messageBody proxima-nova, HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
```

I have tried something like `window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property)` but it returns the same for normal characters and that of the particular characters I have mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean "distinguish" ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I need to differentiate between the normal font i use in the message and one that I copied from the font generator

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. Will try this.

Comment: Are you trying to find whether a font is actually being used? I can’t understand what is meant by differentiate between a normal font and one from a font generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getComputedStyle()` won't work for the `o` and `ℍ` examples you've shown. This is because they are using extended Unicode characters, not CSS font styling.

If you want to detect those characters, you can check the Unicode value of the character. For example the standard `A-z` is 65-122. If it's outside of those bounds then you can perform whatever action you require on that character, either replacing it with a more appropriate character, or removing it entirely. Note that you may want to include some additional codes for symbols etc. depending on your exact use case.

```js
console.log('Hello'.charCodeAt(0)); // = 72

console.log('ℍ'.charCodeAt(0)); // = 8461
console.log('o'.charCodeAt(0)); // = 55349
```